# How to fix -- Formula cannot use another formula field that directly or indirectly refers to itself

Tags: formula

I'm trying to create formula field in my custom object and my code looks like this:

```
IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Case_Source__c  , "OLS" )), AND(ISPICKVAL(Case_Source__c  , "Delta" ), Delta_SR__c  <> NULL ),  IMAGE('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150b000001tNEA'," ",12,15)+Delta_SR__c , Delta_SR__c  , HYPERLINK( "https://Your_SF_SERVER.salesforce.com/"+Id ,""+ DeltaSR__c ) )
```

but it showing the error:

> Formula cannot use another formula field that directly or indirectly
>   refers to itself.

Comment: Your formula field can't directly or indirectly reference itself. If Salesforce would allow that you could create infinite loops and those are hard to calculate. What is the name of your formula field, what is the field type of Case_Source__c and what is the field type of Delta_SR__c?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, if formula A references formula B, which in turn references formula A, you'll get this error, or if formula A references formula A. Presumably, since you have a Delta_SR__c field and a DeltaSR__c field, it looks like you accidentally referenced your formula field from itself. I believe you meant:

```
HYPERLINK( "https://Your_SF_SERVER.salesforce.com/"+Id ,""+ Delta_SR__c ) )
```

Comment: but still getting on error.

Comment: IF(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Case_Source__c  , "OLS" )), 
(AND(ISPICKVAL(Case_Source__c  , "Delta" ), Delta_SR__c  <> NULL ),
 IMAGE('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150b000001tNEA'," ",12,15)+Delta_SR__c , Delta_SR__c )
, HYPERLINK( "https://Your_SF_SERVER.salesforce.com/"+Id , Delta_SR__c  ))

Comment: getting the error as: " Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'"  can you help

Comment: @sudha Yes, your parentheses are messed up. Unfortunately, I'm not sure *what* you meant, so I'm not sure how to help you. I answered your first question, but I'm not sure what you're intending to do overall.