# Formula field to show parent's value or use logic

Tags: formula-field

I need to build a formula field in the opportunity that fetches a parent opportunity's value of the same field or executes some logic as following:

```
IF( NOT(ISNULL(Lookup_opp_field__c)), Lookup_opp_field__r.Formula__c, [executes some logic])
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> Formula cannot use another formula field that directly or indirectly
> refers to itself

Is there anyway to go around this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix -- Formula cannot use another formula field that directly or indirectly refers to itself](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229124/how-to-fix-formula-cannot-use-another-formula-field-that-directly-or-indirect)

Comment: thanks @PrzemysławDługoszewski-Tamoń, but it does not. the requirement is really to get the parent record's formula value. I think this is a database limitation. which I guess it makes sense, but i wondered if someone had a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you can't recursively reference a formula.

You'll need to duplicate the formula you have in the "else" portion of the `IF()` and use `Lookup_opp_field__r.<field here>` instead of simply `<field here>`

Comment: This is the solution that I currently implemented. But I can have many levels of relationship. Meaning I can have an opportunity with a great-great-great-great-grandparent for example. I needed to know if there is anyway of getting the original value.